# Can a DOM event be allowed its default behaviour after it's been stopped or prevented?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events

I'd like to **allow the default event behaviour of certain elements** (ie. `<a>` and `<form>`) until I can be certain that items in the Google Analytics queue have been processed.

I've seen many methods that involve adding an event listener that stops the passed event (`event.stop()` or `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false`), or prevents its default behaviour (`event.preventDefault()`). This then requires that the behaviour be somehow re-written, instead of just passing/activating/releasing the original event.

For example, with mootools, I could use the following event handler on `<a id="special-a-element">` to push and process a GA event before redirecting to the target document:

```
$('special-a-element').addEvent('click', function() {
    var url = this.get('href');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action']);
    _gaq.push(function() { document.location = url; });
    return false;
});
```

Here, the `document.location` recreates what the browser might do if it were allowed to deal with the `click` event I've stopped (with `return false`); this seems unnecessary. What if `special-a-element` had `target = "_blank"`? The listener would not open the link in a new window, but in the current one (because of `document.location`).

So I would like to **allow the default behaviour without stopping it then re-implementing it**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Changed the wording, as I hope to allow the default event handling behaviour to happen _once_ my additional code has finished; _delaying_ the default behaviour isn't exactly what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like...

```
$(...).addEvent(function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    e.target.parentNode.dispatchEvent(e)
  }, 1000);

  // cancel the event
  return false;
})
```

Comment: I could, but adding a timeout isn't really what I'm after. I want to **allow the default behaviour once some other code has run**, not _delay_ the default behaviour for a while in which some other code _is likely_ to have run, dig?

Answer (score -1):

You could implement a `sleep` function and use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        // do other stuff here
        sleepUntilGAReady();
    });
});

function sleepUntilGAReady() {
    var GAReady = false;
    while (!GAReady) {
         sleep(500);        
         GAReady = /* check if it's done */;
    }
}

function sleep(miliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() - start < miliseconds); 
}
```

Or, if you don't need the time delay, just do it like in sleep() - `while (!/* check if GA is ready */);` in the end of the event you want to delay.

Comment: Yeah, I had a loop waiting for the okay from GA (that is, pushing `function(){allowEvent = true;}` into `_gaq` and then `while(!allowEvent);` before `return true;` in the event handler, but that doesn't seem right, you know?

Comment: @lucasrizoli: I agree with you, didn't feel right using it in this example as well, but it gets the job done